# Force PHP SoapClient to use HTTP GET request

Tags: php, soap, http-headers

I have to interface with a SOAP server that will only accept http GET requests (Using POST results in a 'bad-request' error).

I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation PHP documentation on how to to this so grasping at straws I attempted to set a request header using stream_context

```
$soap_client = new SoapClient($wsdl,
        array(
            "trace" => $trace,
            "exceptions" => $exceptions,
            'proxy_host' => $proxyHost,
            "proxy_port" => $proxyPort,
            "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array('http' => array("header" => "request: GET")))
            ));
```

With no success. Does anyone know how I can force a http get request when using SoapClient?

Comment: You could write your own class extending SoapClient and implement the `__doRequest` method to perform the request using `GET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research and I've found that GET request was introduced in SOAP 1.2, but in general SOAP doesn't support GET request while REST does.

I think there's a workaround possible in some cases. It's not the straightforward solution, as there not so many problems that have those.

SOAP is sending data via POST. In GET request you can only use the URL and wrap any parameters to variables like

```
http://server.domain/path/file.php?var1=value1&var2=value2&etc=etc
```

So if the SOAP only accept GET, it's strange, but if you know, you can pass the data in the variable xml you can try to send it by URL:

```
http://server.domain/path/file.php?xml=encoded_data
```

If that's true (which I'm not sure) then you can use the SOAP client, then dump the request like in here: http://www.herongyang.com/ws/php_soap_2.html

```
echo("\nDumping request headers:\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
echo("\nDumping request:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest());
echo("\nDumping response headers:\n" . $client->__getLastResponseHeaders());
echo("\nDumping response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse());
```

and then "encode" the xml from $client->__getLastRequest(), pass it to the URL and send it by curl.

Comment: I'm under the impression that its still sending the XML as POST however is for some reason requiring the header to be to set as GET. Unfortunately the only access I have to this server is through the SOAP interface so I can't be sure. I have successfully tested the service using Wizdler (chrome plugin) by setting the request type to GET however I'm not sure how Wizdler sends the XML data.